# Why is my nonlinear model fitting in mathematica not providing small figures?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
#dataset, sigmoidal curve
ratio278a267 ={{5.445, 0.0501}, {6.177, 0.035}, {7., 0.0589}, {7.368, 
  0.0953}, {7.73, 0.1419}, {8.169, 1.0697}, {9.141, 1.0869}, {10.3, 
  1.0981}} 

#nonlinearmodelfitting for dataset
fit = FindFit[ratio278a267, (1/(a + (E^(-b*(x - c))))), {a, b, c}, x]
fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[
   ratio278a267, (1/(a + (E^(-b*(x - c))))), {a, b, c}, x]["RSquared"]

#fit1 & fit2 output respectively
output:
{a -> 0.639719, b -> -250.201, c -> -1008.92}
0.
```

The code above is what i used for a nonlinear fitting in Mathematica, and the output has not provided reasonably small figures, despite me having plotted this in a graphing calculator overlaid ontop of my dataset, with numbers between 0-10 for a,b,c and have obtained reasonable fitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get `FindFit` to converge on a good solution is to give it good starting values, particularly when your model could give wildly bad fits for some values of the values.

```
x=.;a=.;b=.;c=.;
ratio278a267 ={{5.445, 0.0501}, {6.177, 0.035}, {7., 0.0589}, {7.368,0.0953},
  {7.73, 0.1419}, {8.169, 1.0697}, {9.141, 1.0869}, {10.3,1.0981}};
fit = FindFit[ratio278a267, (1/(a+(E^(-b*(x-c))))), {{a,0.92}, {b,8.7}, {c,7.9}}, x]
Show[ListPlot[ratio278a267],Plot[(1/(a+(E^(-b*(x-c)))))/.fit,{x,5.445,10.3}]]
```

In this example I found those starting values by doing ten thousand Monte Carlo trials looking for the smallest sum of squared error between the model and the data points and then let `FindFit` converge on the best values that it could find.

Comment: Hey @Bill, thanks for the comment, I found that additionally my error was not using 'E' instead. afterwards my code gave good values for the coefficients, thanks!